# Can not Run R connection code in SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server

I try to run R code in SQL Server and it works, but if I want to get a second dataset with a connection string (`odbc`, `RxSqlServerData`) from the database then I always get an error.

The error looks like this:

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 1
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004. External script request id is CCEAB520-FED1-4FF3-8C36-772231352704.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
An external script error occurred: 

[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]SQL Server existiert nicht oder Zugriff verweigert.
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][Shared Memory]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).
```

I read already that I need to create a `SQLRUserGroup` Login and grant access and I did but the error message did not change.

Comment: I think i found the issue, I need activate TCP/IP in the SQL Configurations